# PHP - Transfer Data from table to another within a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm still new to PHP programming, my goal here is to

-transfer data from Table to another Table

```
<html> <head> <title>Sending Application Form by Email</title> </head> <body>

<?PHP

include ("dbase.php");

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
    {
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee_database WHERE Employee_Name= '$username'");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {       
    $insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `leave_requested`
                            (`Employee_Name`,
                            `Employee_ID`,
                            `Designation`,
                            `Department`,
                            `Days_on_Leave`, 
                            `Leave_Start_On`,
                            `Leave_End_On`,
                            `Reason for Leave`)
                     SELECT `Employee_Name`,
                            `Employee_ID`,
                            `Designation`,
                            `Department`,
                            '$Days',
                            '$Start',
                            '$End',
                            '$Reason'
                       FROM `employee_database`
                      WHERE `Employee_Name` = '$username'");
/*  
    ("INSERT INTO leave_requested (Employee_Name, Employee_ID, Designation, Department, Days_on_Leave, Leave_Start_On, Leave_End_On, Reason for Leave)
    SELECT Employee_Name, Employee_ID, Designation, Department FROM employee_database




    VALUES ('$row[Employee_Name]','$row[Employee_ID]','$row[Designation]','$row[Department]','$_POST['No_Days']','$_POST['StartDate']','$_POST['EndDate']','$_POST['Leave_Reason']')");
    */
    }
}
mysql_close ($qry);
?>

<?php
    require("C:\AppServ\www\Project\PHPMailer_5.2.4\class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();

//GMAIL config
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; //                                                    Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; //                                                   Sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; //                                        Sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = '587'; //                                                   Sets the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->Username = ("my@gmail.com"); //                              SMTP UserName (Email Address)
$mail->Password = "******"; //                                              SMTP PassWord (Email Address PassWord)
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //                                                        Enables SMTP debug information (for testing)## 1 = errors and messages ## 2 = messages only ##

$mail->From = $mail->Username; //                                               Sender Email Account on Email
$mail->FromName = 'HR Management'; //                                                   Sender Name on Email

$mail->AddAddress('my@yahoo.com', 'JD'); //                 Add a recipient Email and Name
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = '$username have added Leave Requested'; //                                         Email Subject
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>'; //            HTML Plain Text
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients'; // HTML Function

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
    echo 'Message has been sent';
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be glad if anyone were to able to send an example of 2 sql query. Thanks

The error now I'm getting is an odd one, i haven't encounter this type of ERROR before.
Do anyone have knowledge on this ERROR. Please suggest a solution to this ERROR. Thanks

*Page Error*

```
*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #4' at line 1
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! You can improve your question explaining why the second query does not fits your needs. Does it gives an error? Does it fails saving the data you need? Please add some details about that. Thanks!

Comment: What is the name for the site? I would love to move any user of my choice into leave requested table.

Comment: Your Common Sense,
Luckily this is for a private server, is made for a subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee_database WHERE Employee_Name= '$username'");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

In the first line, [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

In the second line, you pass the return value back into another call to [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query).

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) expects a SQL query string as parameter.

Easy fix:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee_database WHERE Employee_Name= '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Some further tips:

1. [google error messages](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=You+have+an+error+in+your+SQL+syntax%3B+check+the+manual+that+corresponds+to+your+MySQL+server+version+for+the+right+syntax+to+use+near+%27Resource+id+%234%27+at+line+1) before consulting on a forum
2. read the documentation before consulting a forum
3. don't use [mysql extension in PHP, it is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)!
4. use prepared statements - your code is prone to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection)

Comment: OP has changed the question. My answer was correct before changing. After trying my suggestion he encountered a new problem and asked it editing this instead of asking a new one. I have not optimized his query. He copied my query and edited it later.

Answer (score 0):

First I have to tell you about your query that it is prone to SQL injection. Second `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and no more will be supported.

You can do it with sinle query. You may use this query:

```
 INSERT INTO `leave_requested` (`Employee_Name`, 
                              `Employee_ID`, 
                              `Designation`, 
                              `Department`, 
                              `Days_on_Leave`, 
                              `Leave_Start_On`, 
                              `Leave_End_On`, 
                              `Reason for Leave`) 
                       SELECT `Employee_Name`, 
                              `Employee_ID`, 
                              `Designation`, 
                              `Department`, 
                              '$_POST[\'No_Days\']', 
                              '$_POST[\'StartDate\']', 
                              '$_POST[\'EndDate\']', 
                              '$_POST[\'Leave_Reason\']' 
                         FROM `employee_database` 
                        WHERE `Employee_Name` = '$username'
```

Comment: Thanks for you Concern Ozkan, but this wont be my last programming that I working on.

I managed to fiddle my codes around with your suggested coding. It work only 90%. 

Error Page:

    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #4' at line 1

Comment: Let me tell you what I am thinking. You just copied the code and ran.

Comment: -1, Not actually answering the OP's question. He asked for the reason of the error message. He did not ask you to optimize his queries.

Comment: @Kaii no problem. I do not care about points. Here to learn and help as much as I can do. So I have given you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html).  (I've linked to MySQL documentation, but so far as I know it's standard SQL.)

Comment: -1, Not actually answering the OP's question. He asked for the reason of the error message. He did not ask you to optimize his queries.

Comment: @Kaii if you wish to check the edit history as to what the question was originally, this answer may make more sense. :|